# Creating a List Definition in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, list-definition

Dont know if I'm missing something or just blind, but did MS not include the Add new List Definition template to VS2012 ? It was there in VS2010.

#### VS 2010 screenshot

[image: VS 2010 screenshot]

#### VS 2012 screenshot

[image: VS 2012 screenshot]

Comment: Sorry about the external links but i'm not allowed to upload images yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I believe this is the case.

When creating a **List** by the template shown in your screenshots a List Definition is also created, and then you can delete the List Instance. If you do this the *List* tab will simply not be clickable, and you can design your independent List Definition.

[Walkthrough: Create a Site Column, Content Type, and List for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx)