# Deleted List instance in Visual Studio for a list definition, how to get it back?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio

I have deleted list instance that Visual Studio created for me, how can I recreate it in Visual Studio using list definition?

Comment: Kind of guessing here, but check: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45568/creating-a-list-definition-in-visual-studio-2012. In your case, I assume that you'll get the *List instance* by creating a new **List**.

Comment: moe, that is the opposite of what i want, thank you

Comment: I agree, but by creating a (new) List you'll get the instance too? In that topic the questioner just wants (re)create another object created by the List template.

Comment: see, i have 300 columns in my list, i did not wanted to create a new list definition, thank you